# Creating a API-call with Angular resource

Tags: angularjs

I am currently trying to make an API call in my angular model, but not quite sure how to format it.

Since the format of the web-url is different depending on what I want I will need different calls.

```
this.searchOne= $resource('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie', ?query= *USER INPUT HERE*, &api_key=XXXXXXXXX")
this.searchTwo = $resource(https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/*USER INPUT HERE*/videos, &api_key=XXXX)
```

But obviously this doesnt work. Because I have no idea how to write the code with user input before /string and so on.

The controller side code would look something like this, but I cant manage to get the user input in the right place.

```
$scope.searchFunction= function(){
var input= $("#someVariable").val();
Dinner.DishSearch.get({userinput},function(data){
 $scope.movies=data.Results;
 $scope.status = "Showing " + data.Results.length + " results";
   },function(data){
     $scope.status = "There was an error";
   });
};
```

Would appreciate any help how I could format the resource to have the end strings look like this:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/USERINPUT/videos6api_key=XXXX
and
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=USERINPUT&api_key=XXXX

Answer (score 0):

According [the $resource service docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) you can provide several actions with different urls as third argument

```
var baseUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
var movieDB = $resource(baseUrl, {api_key: 'XXXX'}, {
   getVideos: {url: baseUrl + 'movie/:query/videos', isArray: true}
   search: {url: baseUrl + 'search/movie', isArray: true}
});
```

I suppose that this api urls return an array of results, so do not forget to pass `isArray: true` to make it work.

Then you can use this resource as you want

```
movieDB.getVideos({query: userinput}, function(data) {});
movieDB.search({query: userinput}, function(data) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You can create a variable which holds common part of each api call i.e. baseUrl = "api.themoviedb.org/3/" 
.This string can be concatenated to remaining part each time which is going to change according to different calls.
for example: `baseUrl+"/search/movie"`

Moreover, for making  the following kind of api calls in which data goes in search part of url as in your case:
"api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=USERINPUT&api_key=XXXX"

you can use **$location.search** method  in angular (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

**as per angular docs:**

`search(search, [paramValue]);`

This method is getter/setter. It returns search part (as object) of current url when called without any parameter.It changes search part when called with parameter and return $location.

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
// set foo to 'yipee'
$location.search('foo', 'yipee');
 // $location.search() => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}
```